# Python - How to rename images used in the material of an object?

Tags: python

I want to rename the image texture used inside the material of an object?

Comment: Do you want to rename the image texture's node; do you want to rename the actual image; or do you mean by "rename" that you want to replace the image with a different one?

Comment: I would suggest listing what is "known" or "given" in your question as the appropriate answer may vary. Such as if you know the original image name and only want to rename the image that can be in `bpy.data.images[{original image name}].name` if you know the material then you don't need to know the material slot since it can be accessed through `bpy.data.materials`. If you only know the object you may need to test for multiple material slots. And finally keep in mind a single material could potentially have multiple image nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Consider the Material Slot 1

[image]

```
import bpy

mat     = bpy.context.object.data.materials[0]
tree    = mat.node_tree
node    = tree.nodes["Image Texture"]
img     = node.image

# rename node
node.name = "Image Texture 2"

# rename image
img.name = "new_img"
```